# Chrome headless is throwing nosuchelements

Tags: python, selenium, windows-10, headless, google-chrome-headless

Chrome headless is throwing nosuchelements and timeout exception for all the scripts in my suite when running on windows 10, when running the same script by commenting the piece of code that set the chrome options to headless, the script is running successfully.
Also, the script is running successfully on Mac os with headless chrome.

Other details
Platform: windows 10
Chrome version: 74
Scripts written using selenium and python

Kindly let me know if any further details required, Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: below are the chrome options that i am using options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--headless')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of headless browser you have to set the window size to fire on event.Because headless browser can't recognise where to click without window size.Hope it will work.Give it a try.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
```

Comment: options.headless = True

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I am still getting the same error. I even tried to capture screenshot  after the webdriver.get() method. But the screenshot is completely blank